# Why does raster::crop change values of my RasterLayer?

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm having a curious problem with the raster::crop function. When I crop a large raster containing unique ID values (equal to cell number) the resulting smaller raster contains duplicated values where each cell should be unique.

I have a large raster (r) cropped to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of the African continent. I want to generate a unique ID for each grid cell and then crop the larger RasterLayer to a smaller polygon (one country) – this way, I would be able to subsequently merge data from smaller raster calculations to the larger raster based on their unique cell IDs.

However, when I crop the larger raster containing the unique IDs, the new raster layer does not contain unique IDs – rather, there is a large amount of duplicated values. From what I can tell, it seems that some ID values are replaced by neighbouring values, thus producing patterns like e.g. 301,301,303,303,306,306,306 instead of continuously increasing by 1 (within the same row of course). The larger r contains only unique values so the issue arises only after cropping the raster to a smaller raster.

Projection is the same in polygon and raster and I am using the latest version of the Raster package.

The problem seems to appear only for high resolution rasters. Using raster::mask instead to replace cells outside the polygon with NAs also produces duplicates in some cases.

The problem is a complete mystery to me – I haven't been able to find any possible reason for this. Does anyone know if there are issues with the crop function and how it handles values? Even if I figure out another way to do this, I wonder if this problem occurs for other rasters and, thus, that your data is corrupted some how in the crop function. I hope someone can help me figure out what the problem is.

I created a small example below that reproduces the problem. If you need further information, let me know.

```
pack <- c("sp", "raster", "rgdal", "dplyr")
lapply(pack, require, character.only = TRUE); rm(pack)

r <- raster(africa, resolution = 1/60/2) ## Create empty raster layer based on extent of Africa polygons and resolution 30 arc seconds. 
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r) ## Generate unique cell ID (equal to cell number)
poly <- africa[3,] ## Subset one country

r_id <- crop(r, poly) ## Crop r to poly
## This is the function that seems to be responsible for the unexpected result. It should return a smaller raster containing the same values in the same cells as the larger raster. Therefore each grid cell value in r_id should be unique. 

as.data.frame(r_id) %>% ## This just to show that the resulting raster contains duplicate values where none should exist
  group_by(layer) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n))

# A tibble: 137,270 x 2
      layer     n
      <dbl> <int>
 1 24774556     3
 2 24774560     3
 3 24774564     3
 4 24774568     3
 5 24774572     3
 6 24774576     3
 7 24774580     3
 8 24774584     3
 9 24774588     3
10 24774592     3
# ... with 137,260 more rows.
```

Comment: Apologies, packages are included in the code now. They are "sp", "rgdal", "raster", and "dplyr".

Comment: I get `Error in raster(africa, resolution = 1/60/2) : object 'africa' not found`

Comment: Sorry, I use a customised SpatialPolygons for Africa (and don't know how to attach files). Tried using the built in world data set from "tmap" but wasn't able to reproduce the problem. Anyway, I am also currently unable to reproduce the problem on the original data/code so for now I hope that it was a glitch in my data/code that was somehow fixed (although I still don't know why the problem occurred in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the imprecision of a numeric value for larger numbers when the values are written to disk using 4 byte floating point numbers.

I suspect this happens in your case because `r` is backed up by a (temporary) file. Have a look at the data source after setting the cell numbers

```
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
r
```

I illustrate this here

```
library(raster)
a <- 24774556:24774565
r <- raster(ncol=2, nrow=5)
values(r) <- a
x <- writeRaster(r, "test1.grd", overwrite=TRUE)
v <- values(x)
v
#[1] 24774556 24774556 24774558 24774560 24774560 24774560 24774562 24774564 24774564 24774564
table(v)
#v
#24774556 24774558 24774560 24774562 24774564 
#       2        1        3        1        3
```

However if you set the datatype to "FLT8S" or "INT4U":

```
y <- writeRaster(r, "test2.grd", datatype="FLT8S", overwrite=TRUE)
values(y)
#[1] 24774556 24774557 24774558 24774559 24774560 24774561 24774562 24774563 24774564 24774565


z <- writeRaster(r, "test3.grd", datatype="INT4U", overwrite=TRUE)
values(z)
# [1] 24774556 24774557 24774558 24774559 24774560 24774561 24774562 24774563 24774564 24774565
```

In your case, you may consider, instead of `values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)`, doing

```
 r <- init(r, "cell", datatype="FLT8S", filename="africa_id.grd")
```

Or, skip this bit all together. You can also crop parts, process, and then use `merge` to put the cropped pieces back together.